# Can a C struct be defined multiple times?

Tags: c, struct

I've read in several places that a C struct can safely be defined multiple times, and yet I get a "redefinition of struct" error from gcc for multiply defining a struct (through multiple includes). A very simplified example looks like this:

foo.c:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct bar b;
  b.a = 2;
  return 0;
}
```

a.h:

```
struct bar {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

b.h:

```
#include "a.h"

struct buz {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

If I run `gcc foo.c` I get:

```
In file included from b.h:1:0,
                 from foo.c:2:
a.h:1:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct bar’
a.h:1:8: note: originally defined here
```

I know I haven't put any include guards and those will fix the compile error, but my understanding was that this should work nonetheless. I also tried two `struct bar` definitions in foo.c and I get the same error message? So, can structs be defined mutiple times in C or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A struct in C can be *declared* multiple times safely, but can only be defined once.

```
    struct bar;
    struct bar{};
    struct bar;
```

compiles fine, because bar is only defined once and declared as many times as you like.

Comment: yeah, basically every thing in C can be declared multiple times but define one once.

Answer (score 0):

The struct can only be defined once for each file you compile. Here, you are including a.h twice. (Once directly and once via b.h.)

You need to change your code so that the symbol is only defined once for a given source file.

Answer (score 0):

No they can't be defined multiple times and that is why you have #ifndef include guards and should use them.

Having

```
#include "a.h"
```

inside b.h header file means you redefine bar. If you had #ifndef include guards this would not be happening.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have #ifdef macros in your header file. If you include your headers in multiple source files, you will encounter that error.

Answer (score 0):

The same symbol in the same scope cannot be defined twice. What you are probably referring to is that it is safe to include the struct from two different C files which essentially means that they are defined twice (since there is no export) and sharing these structs won't be a problem, since they are compiled to the same memory layout